# Remove an event listener after firing once or any number of times

Tags: javascript, event-handling, callback

> Remove an event listener after firing once or any number of times

This is what I have:

```
/*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
(function ()
{
    "use strict";

    function removeEventListenerAfterFiring(numberOfTimes, callback, useCapture)
    {
        var count = 0;
        return function listener(event)
        {
            count += 1;

            if (count >= numberOfTimes)
            {
                event.target.removeEventListener(event.type, listener, useCapture);
            }

            callback();
        };
    }

    function functionName()
    {
        // Code here.
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", removeEventListenerAfterFiring(1, functionName, false), false);
}());
```

Is there anything that could be improved, or is there a better way to do this?

Is it acceptable to specify `useCapture` twice? Is there a way to detect if `useCapture` has been specified so that I don't have to pass it to the `removeEventListenerAfterFiring` function?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`, since your handlers are probably bound to an ancestor element, not the current element.